# What is good style for variable declaration in fortran?

Tags: coding-style, fortran, fortran77

So I have a whole lot of variables I need to declare, and the original code looked like this:

```
    DIMENSION energy_t(20000),nrt(20000),npsh(1000),xx(1000),yy(1000),
    :step(1000),stepz(1000),r1(1000),rr(1000),ic(1000),diffrr(1000)
```

And I rewrote it as this:

```
    DIMENSION
    :energy_t(20000),
    :nrt(20000),
    :npsh(1000),
    :step(1000),
    :r1(1000),
    :rr(1000),
    :ic(1000),
    :diffrr(1000)
```

Is this considered good style, or are there better ways? Note that the second way allows for comments with each variable, and I don't have to use line continuations if I might add another variable.

P.S.: is there a consensus/style bible/widely regarded source on Fortran programming style & good practices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good style is not to use the dimension statement in the first place. Especially if you use implicit typing. Every variable should have a declared type and is better to put the array dimension there. Use attributes with the type declaration (Fortran 90+).

```
real :: energy_t(20000), nrt(20000)
real, dimension(1000) :: npsh, xx, yy, step, stepz, r1, rr, ic, diffrr
```

Keep lines not too long. Both ways of declaring size (shape) are possible.

If you need Fortran 77, you are more limited, but still

```
real energy_t(20000), nrt(20000)
real npsh(1000), xx(1000), yy(1000), step(1000), stepz(1000)
real r1(1000), rr(1000), ic(1000), diffrr(1000)
```

is probably better.

Try to group related variables on one line and the others on different lines.

I would also suggest to declare `parameter` constants for the sizes 1000 and 20000.

Comment: A (possibly very minor) point: beware implicit typing converting from `DIMENSION` statement to `DIMENSION` attribute.

Comment: What is wrong with dimension? I must say that the program uses "IMPLICIT REAL*8 (a-h,o-z)", if that has any relevance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong per se with the dimension statement, but it does tend to be strongly coupled with (unloved) implicit typing.  Further, having type and attributes together in the declaration is much nicer than having to hunt around code to get a full idea of what a variable means.  [Admittedly, in F77 there are many fewer attributes, but still...]

Comment: @PatronBernard I'd recommend against implicit typing.

Comment: Yeah I suspect that this code was written ten years ago by some stubborn physics professor who learned F77 thirty years ago.

Why do the lines have to be reasonably long? What is the motivation behind that?

Comment: Why "reasonably long lines"?   So that they are easily readable.  While the Fortran >= 90 standards allow 132 characters, depending on your terminal, editor, font, etc., that long may be hard to read.

Comment: But that's pretty subjective, no? I feel that declaring these variables in a column with line continuation gives a better overview, allows comments with each variable (as is in this case, this code had no comments with the variables and I still have no clue what some of them do). Then again, a variable name should be picked carefully too, which I think is not the case with this code. It's clearly coded by someone who was really "into" what he/she was doing at the time, disregarding any future use.

Comment: Yes, if the variables are really different, and single comment for them is not enough, why not just one on one line? That would be a rather short line I guess.

Comment: But short lines aren't a problem if they improve readability, IMHO. I'm sorry if this is a pointless argument about a pretty subjective matter.

Comment: No, of course not. By reasonably long I certainly meant not too long.

Answer (score 0):

Good style would be to parametrize the dimensions

```
integer, parameter:: NODES_MAX = 1000, TIMES_MAX = 2000, COORD_MAX = 1000
real energy_t(TIMES_MAX), ..
real npsh(NODES_MAX), xx(COORD_MAX) ...
```

so that the loops can be parameterized.

```
do ii = 1, COORD_MAX
    xx(ii) = ...
    yy(ii) = ..
end do
```

and error checks can be made

```
if (ii .gt. NODES_MAX) then
    print *, 'Please increase NODES_MAX oldvalue=', NODES_MAX, ' required=', ii
    pause
end if
```

This will also minimize the number of changes required when the dimensions are increased/decreased.  This style could also have been applied 30+ years ago when F77 came out.